# Archiving files with 7-zip, upload to FTP-server only current date files and then delete

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, archiving

In one script I have few steps:

- Archiving files by 7-zip, compress, encrypt, delete source file after archiving
- Then I transfer to FTP server files from step 1.
- Then I delete old files from step 1.

My script:

```
REM 7-zip archiving, compress, encryption, delete source file

@echo off
set source="D:\test"
set destination="D:\test"
set passwd="Qwerty"
set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
set mm=%DATE:~3,2%
set yyyy=%DATE:~6%
set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
set mm=%TIME:~3,2%
set ss=%TIME:~6,2%
set curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%-%hh%-%mm%-%ss%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -ssw -mx9 -xr!*.7z -p%passwd% %destination%\backup_%curdate%.7z %source% -sdel

REM Send to FTP server by cmd ftp

set ftp_host=127.0.0.1
set ftp_username=test
set ftp_pass=test
set file_transport=transport.txt
set file_name="*.7z"
set dir_from=D:\test
set dir_to=/
echo open %ftp_host%>%file_transport%
echo user %ftp_username% %ftp_pass%>>%file_transport%
echo cd %dir_to%>>%file_transport%
echo lcd %dir_from%>>%file_transport%
echo put %file_name%>>%file_transport%
echo bye>>%file_transport%
ftp -v -n -s:%file_transport%
del %file_transport%

REM delete old files older than N days
forfiles /p "D:\test" /d -30 /m *.7z /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

So problem is:

When i try send to ftp-server, I don't know how to send only files `%.7z%` current day. Even if I use `file_name="*.7z"` it works only for first archive from directory `dir_from=D:\test`, but if I have this value it must send all from `D:\test`.
I was trying to use *ncFTP* for this task, but i cant understand how it works, this not working:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NcFTP Software\NcFTPncftpput.exe" -u "test" -p "test" "127.0.0.1"  "/" "D:\test"
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `PUT` and `MPUT`? Your script knows what file it is zipping so I am not sure why you don't use the whole file name instead of the wildcard.

Comment: I try now use MPUT instead PUT, but in this case script stuck in "ftp>".
i think i get it. I just replace set file_name="*.7z" to set file_name="backup_%curdate%.7z".
Thank you.

Comment: Now appear new question about this script. I dont want create new question, so write here. How exclude situation when no files in D:\test, only 7z files. I need some IF operator for this. I tryied like this, something like:
IF FILE !*.7z EXIST %do archivation 7-zip that in script% ELSE goto nextstep.
For now if script doesnt see new files its just create empty 7z archive.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "source=D:\test"
set "destination=D:\test"
set "dirs="." "fullbackup" "diffbackup""
set "passwd=Qwerty"
set "dd=%DATE:~0,2%"
set "mm=%DATE:~3,2%"
set "yyyy=%DATE:~6%"
set "hh=%TIME:~0,2%"
set "mn=%TIME:~3,2%"
set "ss=%TIME:~6,2%"
set "curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%-%hh%-%mn%-%ss%"
set "logfile=%cd%\log.tmp"

REM Make the logfile if not exist.
if not exist "%logfile%" 1> nul 2> "%logfile%" echo.

REM Make ftp file.
set "ftp_host=127.0.0.1"
set "ftp_username=test"
set "ftp_pass=test"
set "file_transport=transport.txt"
set "ftp_root=/"

(
    echo open %ftp_host%
    echo user %ftp_username% %ftp_pass%
    echo binary
) > "%file_transport%"

REM Zip files.
set "zipped=0"

for %%A in (%dirs%) do if exist "%source%\%%~A" (
    set "setdir="

    for %%B in ("%source%\%%~A\*") do if /i not "%%~xB" == ".7z" (
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -ssw -mx9 -p"%passwd%" "%destination%\%%~A\%%~nxB_%curdate%.7z" "%%~fB" -sdel

        if not errorlevel 1 (
            set /a "zipped+=1"
            >> "%logfile%" echo zip "%%~A\%%~nxB_%curdate%.7z".

            if not defined setdir (
                set "setdir=1"
                if not "%%~A" == "." echo mkdir "%ftp_root%/%%~A"
                echo cd "%ftp_root%/%%~A"
                echo lcd "%destination%\%%~A"
            )

            echo put "%%~nxB_%curdate%.7z"
        ) >> "%file_transport%"
    )
)

>> "%file_transport%" echo bye

REM Send to FTP server by cmd ftp.
if %zipped% equ 0 (
    >> "%logfile%" echo zip no files for "%curdate%".
) else (
    ftp -v -n -i -s:"%file_transport%"

    if errorlevel 1 (
        >> "%logfile%" echo ftp error %errorlevel%.
    ) else >> "%logfile%" echo ftp success.
)

del "%file_transport%"

REM Delete old files older than N days.
for %%A in (%dirs%) do if exist "%destination%\%%~A\*.7z" (
    pushd "%destination%\%%~A" && (
        echo CD: "%destination%\%%~A"
        forfiles /d -30 /m *.7z /c "cmd /c del @file"
        popd
    )
)

REM Email the log content.
if not exist "%logfile%" exit /b 0

set command=^&{$usr= 'mylogon';^
$pwd= ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'mypassword' -AsPlainText -Force;^
$cred= New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $usr, $pwd;^
$body= Get-Content -LiteralPath '%logfile%' -Raw;^
Send-MailMessage -To 'mymail' -From 'mymail' -Subject 'Log' -SmtpServer 'smtp.mail.ru' -Port 587 -Credential $cred -UseSSL -Body $body}

Powershell -Command "%command%"

REM Merge or rename .tmp file to .txt file.
for %%A in ("%logfile%") do (
    if "%%~xA" == ".tmp" (
        if exist "%%~nA.txt" (
            type "%%~A" >> "%%~nA.txt"
            del "%%~A"
        ) else ren "%%~A" "%%~nA.txt"
    )
)

exit /b 0
```

Issue of date and time where you use `mm` for month and `mm` for minutes.
Now using `mn` for minutes to separate the values.

All files except .7z files will be individually zipped and available
for `ftp`.

`zipped` variable stores the count of files zipped so `ftp` command
runs only if the value of `zipped` is greater than `0`.

`transport.txt` will have content inserted multiple times,
instead of, all at once. This is done so each directory
and file can be handled separately.

The `for` loops now can iterate a list of directories to zip `*.7z` files.
The `ftp` `put` commands will be echoed to `transport.txt` with each file
zipped.

Simplified write to `%file_transport%` file. Inserted `mkdir` as needed
to ensure the remote directory is created before the `cd` occurs.

`forfiles` now used on each directory specified by the variable `dirs`.

The variable `dirs` contains a list of directory names to iterate through.
`.` is current directory i.e. root of `source` path.

`powershell` will send the `logfile` text content by email with the
cmdlet [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6).
It will not send if the variable `logfile` path does not exist.

If the extension of the logfile is `.tmp`, it will will renamed
with the extension `.txt` if not exist, else will be merged to the
`.txt` file and the `.tmp` file will be deleted.
This is done at the end of the script.
Using extension `.tmp` allows `powershell` to email the content in
the `.tmp` file, instead of the larger `.txt` file.

Comment: I do like this:
ncftpput -u test - p test 127.0.0.1 / "D:\test\backup_%curdate%.7z"
I dont understand what different between PUT and MPUT, i just use ncftpput. You used just PUT for ncftpd, that for Linux not for Windows?
Another questions appear, last 3 i think to finish my script:
1. i try get log file with this:
echo  success backup_%curdate%.7z >> log.txt
But it doesnt work,can't understand why.
2. i try send email with cmd. How i can do this? Examples in internet use telnet, as i understand it is not safe and need activ compnent telnet. Maybe powershell need to use?

Comment: 3. I check my script again it archiving all files that are not 7z in new 7z file, not separate each file.

Comment: Removed quote about *ncFTP* as confusing with using `ftp`. `put` is for single file. `mput` is for multiple files. **1.** I see no issue other then perhaps specify path. **2.** Advise search for an answer to suit your email needs. **3.** Implemeted multiple files i.e 1 file per .7z file.

Comment: 1. i try full path, but doesnt work. I was think that mistake in code, but no, its work from cmd without my script.
2. i try different ways cmd, poweshell but failed to send mail. Have some work example?
4. one more i check again my script and i see that doesnt work deleting old files with FORFILES that i used in my script and my script with your remarks. If i run it just with cmd its work, but not in script

Comment: **1.** So for you, `transport.txt` file works, yet `log.txt` does not. I do not understand why one works and not the other. The update code tested, works with `log.txt` **2.** I have no example. Suggest to [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the code tried. **4.** `forfiles` deletes older files in my testing. I added code to remove trailing backslash from `%destination%` value if exist, to avoid escape of a following double quote used in the `forfiles` command.

Comment: 1. I find a problem when log will not be created, it happened in situation when script nothing to work with, when nothing to archiving+sending FTP.
4. I check again, but no, its not working from script, but without script it works from cmd with "D:\test" against "%destination%" ofcourse. I even try just make another temporary-script near that contain just this:`forfiles /p "D:\test" /d -30 /m *.7z /c "cmd /c del @file"`

Comment: **1.** Log file will be created and will also log if no files to zip. **4.** `/p` argument of `forfiles` selects the path to search, though `/c` argument seems in current directory, so changed to `@path` variable as it is the full path to the file. This may fix the issue.

Comment: 2. i find soltion for mail send from cmd, i do this:
`$EmailFrom = "mymail"`
`$EmailTo = "mymail"`
`$Subject = "Test powershell mail"`
`$Body = "Text"`
`$SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.ru"`
`$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)`
`$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true`
`$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("mylogin", "mypassword")`
`$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)`
It works from cmd and from another srcipt with this: `powershell.exe -File "F:\scripts\mail.ps1"`.
Same from my script not work. I put it in end of myscript.

Comment: 4. Same, it not work, remark for my top comments, it work not only from cmd, but it work in another test script that do only `forfiles`, it works with `@path` and it works with `@file`

Comment: 5. I have one more, last question. How i can do with myscript work `archiving+checking archiving+send ftp+delete files` but in directory level? This script will be work not only with files but with directories. For example MSSQL will put copies in `D:\test\%basename%\fullbackup` and `D:\test\%basename%\diffbackup`. I was thinking if i use script in this version i will need to do many copy of this script with different `%source%` and `%destination%`, that is not comfortable, manual usage. But if i will do all in myscript it will be problem save structure of directories on FTP.

Comment: Updated the answer. **2.** Added powershell command. Change and add arguments to make it work for you. **4.** `pushd` is change current directory before `forfiles` runs, instead of using the argument `/p`. Note that error with finding no files does not mean it failed, just it found no files older than 30 days. **5.** New code handles this. See setting of the variable `dirs`.

Comment: 4. But i use program "filedate changer" to change date file to check deleting old files that older 30 days, so script must find them and delete. So `pushd` "disturb" forfiles and forfiles cant do his job, even when `/p` is specified full path? 5. Well it seems still doesnt work from script.

Comment: 6. Got one more after remarks. When start myscript with your remarks its add old 7z into new 7z and rename it. For example create 1.txt and run myscript he create `1.txt_28-01-2019-17-19-09.7z` in second time whem create 2.txt he create `2.txt_28-01-2019-17-19-55.7z` and he edit `1.txt_28-01-2019-17-19-09.7z` to format `1.txt_28-01-2019-17-19-09.7z_28-01-2019-17-19-55.7z` with `1.txt_28-01-2019-17-19-09.7z` inside with `1.txt`. For me better if `%source%`, `%destination%` will be same as in previous version script, maybe that is problem?

Comment: **4.** I use [BulkFileChanger](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html). The *modified date* needs to changed. If you only change *creation date* then expect `forfiles` to do nothing, as *modified date* may not be older than 30 days. `pushd` does not disturb the process of `forfiles` and `/p` does not exist in latest script. **5.** I do not understand (unless number 6. was the issue for you). It is working in my test environment. **6.** Fixed fault in extension check code of `"%%~xA" == ".7z"` which checks each value of `%dirs%`. Changed to `"%%~xB" == ".7z"` which check files.

Comment: 4. After last your remarks its works, thanks.
5. In powershell script mail.ps1 that i find in internet exist parametrs for login/password and port 587, and its work in my first variant when i run mail.ps1 from another script. When you place it in myscript you change syntaxis, where no options for login, password, port 587. So i think thats why its not work with your remarks from myscript.

Comment: **4.** Good :). **5.** `-Port 587` and `-Credential` using argument of i.e. string type `mylogin` or a *PSCredential* object, such as one from the [Get-Credential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6) cmdlet. Password is prompted except if you look at *Example 7* on the linked page, shows how to include a password which is similar to your PS1 script method of creating a *PSCredential* object. Alternatively, you can run your PS1 script instead, or convert it into the *batch-file* as a command i.e. `&{command;...}`.

Comment: 5. I dont understand how to add in exist contstruction password. As i see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6 there is parameter `-UserName` only.

Comment: I try do this, but it not works:
`powershell $User = "mylogin"` \n
`powershell $Mpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force` \n
`powershell $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $Mpassword` \n
`powershell -Command "& {$body = Get-Content -LiteralPath '%logfile%' -Raw; Send-MailMessage -To 'mymail' -From 'mymail' -Subject 'Log' -SmtpServer 'smtp.mail.ru' -Port 587 -Credential $Credential -Body $body}"`

Comment: Executing `powershell` multiple times may not work. A single execution makes the code work together. Updated the answer with a PS1 script. This can allow you to execute the PS1 script from any other scripts. It has the code similar to what you stated as working for you. You can change the `powershell` command in the batch-file code as needed if you want to use the PS1 file.

Comment: But i think the mail sending will send only once, after all jobs that higher done, dont need to send it multiple times. Sending mail about how many files zipped,send ftp, delete old files. But in simple version i need mail at least something. You advice to me same solution as i proposed, your variant send log file, my not. I try to send from myscript, from myscript.bat, not run from ps1, i think its less complicated. One more, your variant send log file, it will be too much unnecessary information later, log come always bigger, so or need send only current information or just a part of log.

Comment: Updated *batch-file* code with modified `powershell` command. `logfile` uses a `.tmp` extension so only has current session logging and is renamed or merged at end of the script, after the email sent. Removed PS1 code.

Comment: remark, i add `-UseSSL` after `-Credential $cred` or got error about SSL: `SMTP is available only with SSL or TLS connection enabled`.
Thanks, now it works.